# Does Android Activity embedding support custom split?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-windowmanager, android-activitymanager

Does [Android Activity embedding](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/activity-embedding) support custom split like one of these two?

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, the only option available with Activity Embedding is [split task window](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/activity-embedding#split_task_window) - two activities side by side, each completely taking up the entire vertical space for their portion of the screen.